# How to improve edit for Suggested Edit of tag wiki?

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

When there is a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9630588) for tag wiki, I can only either *Accept* it or *Reject* it.

But what if there is only slight thing to improve which I want to suggest, so I don't want to either *Accept* it or *Reject* it or *Skip* it?

I can't see *Improve Edit* option which normally appear for regular posts.

Is this something to be implemented in the future? Or this works deliberately like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can approve suggested edits on tag wikis when you reach 5k, but not edit it without supervision until 20k, it works deliberately like this. When you reach 20k you can do this.

You can accept the edit and wait until it is applied. Then you can suggest a new edit.